# How do I setup Tailwind with npm workspaces?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I have a monorepo set up with npm workspaces, with one space being a "common" space for React components and utils, and two others being apps.

```
- root

-- packages

--- common
--- app1
--- app2
```

All apps use tailwind, and each app has a `package.json` and a `tailwind.config.js` and app1 and app2 import components with:

```
import { Component } from 'common/dist'
```

Tailwind, for obvious reasons, dos not pick up on anything from other packages.
This means that, in app1 and app2, I must add:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    ...
    '../common/src/**/*.{tsx}'
  ]
}
```

This scans the files, yes, but if I defined anything custom in `common/tailwind.confing.js`, then I must also define it in the apps, effectively meaning I have 3 copies of this config.

I know that NX has some way to do this easily, but the choice of monorepo tool is not mine in this case. Is there any way to set up tailwind with a single config file that would catch all the workspaces at once, using npm workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind supports importing other tailwind config files as presets. Try setting the presets array to include require('common/tailwindconfig') or whatever you'd like to call it. Export it from common just like you do with components.